# Predict function in package spaMM resulting in error when third random effect added to linear mixed model

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a linear mixed model using the spaMM package and fitme() function in R, however when I add a third random effect the predict() function cannot be completed.

I would like the meanfit1 model to have one fixed effect:

```
elev
```

and three random effects:

```
Matern(1|long+lat)
1|river_ID
1|source_ID
```

however the predict function does not seem to permit three random effects.

```
Data <- data.frame(source_ID = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
               lat = c(51.63,51.69,51.72,51.69,51.72),
               long = c(1.56,1.51,1.37,1.43,1.60),
               river_ID = c("b","a","b","b","t"),
               elev = c(63,54,32,45,48),
               mean = c(28,28,31,31,27),
               n = rep(5,5),
               var = c(0.1,0.4,0.5,1.5,0.8))

dispfit1 <- fitme(
  formula = var ~ 1 + Matern(1|long + lat) + (1|river_ID) + 
  (1|source_ID),
  family = stats::Gamma(log), data = Data, fixed = list(phi = 2),
  prior.weights = n - 1, control.dist = list(dist.method = 
  "Earth"),
  method = "REML")

Data$disp <- spaMM::predict.HLfit(dispfit1, newdata = Data, variances = 
                              list(respVar = T))

meanfit1 <- fitme(
  formula = mean ~ 1 + elev + Matern(1|long + lat) + (1|river_ID) + 
  (1|source_ID),
  data = Data, resid.model = list(formula = ~0 + offset(disp), family = 
  stats::Gamma(identity)),
  prior.weights = n, control.dist = list(dist.method = "Earth"),
  method = "REML")
```

The code works well if I remove either (1|source_ID) or (1|river_ID), however gives the following error message when all three random effects are included: 'Error in '+'(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00508460138716231, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  operator needs one or two arguments'

Is this a coding problem or a modelling problem?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To the question in the OP,

> Is this a coding problem or a modelling problem?

the answer is that it was a bug in the spaMM source code; the poster's code was correct. spaMM should have been able to evaluate prediction variances for models involving more that two random effects. This bug has been corrected in version 3.0.0 of this [package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=spaMM).